# Understanding Linearization with free-floating bodies and Quaternion States

Tags: drake

I am trying to linearize a free-floating system with a free-floating base and 3 joints (j1, j2, j3). As I understand the positions part of the system state is given by the vector (this matches `MultibodyPlant::num_positions()`):

```
q (10x1) = [base_quaternion (4x1), base_lin_position (3x1), j1_pos, j2_pos, j3_pos]
```

Since angular velocity requires only 3 components, the velocity part of the system state is written as (this matches `MultibodyPlant::num_velocities()`):

```
q_dot (9x1) = [base_rot_vel (3x1), base_lin_vel (3x1), j1_vel, j2_vel, j3_vel]
```

Using this, the full system state is given as (this works when using `MultibodyPlant::SetPositionsAndVelocities`) :

```
X (19x1) = [q (10x1),q_dot (9x1)]
```

With this, the system acceleration resulting from its dynamics and control forces `X_dot = f(X, U)` would be written as:

```
X_dot (18x1)= [q_dot (9x1), q_ddot (9x1)]
```

Due to the difference in the representation of rotations and angular velocities, the number of terms needed to define `X` and `X_dot` is different.

This brings to the following questions while linearizing the system about a point using `Linearize`:

1. The `A` and `B` matrices after linearization of a **continuous-time** `MultibodyPlant` represent the equation `X_dot = A*X + B*u`. However, there seems to be a mismatch here in the sizes of the arrays/matrices involved as `X_dot (18x1)` is different from matrices given by `Linearize`: `A (19x19)` and `B (19x3)`. I don't then understand what accelerations does the matrix `X_dot` from the linear system equation represents with its size `19x1`?
2. The above question is only for a continuous-time case. For a discrete-time system,the following equations hold without any issues with the matrix sizes:`X[n+1] = A_d * X[n] + B_d * u[n]`. However, it is not clear how the quaternion properties are maintained during this linearized forward simulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is misunderstanding in the notation since q_dot ≠ v.
Instead, q_dot is simply the ordinary time-derivative of q.

```
    q (10x1) =     [base_quaternion (4x1), base_lin_position (3x1), j1_pos, j2_pos, j3_pos]
q_dot (10x1) = d/dt[base_quaternion (4x1), base_lin_position (3x1), j1_pos, j2_pos, j3_pos]
```

Angular velocity only has 3 components, so v (the velocity part of the system state) and its time-derivative v_dot are:

```
    v (9x1) =     [base_rot_vel (3x1), base_lin_vel (3x1), j1_vel, j2_vel, j3_vel]
v_dot (9x1) = d/dt[base_rot_vel (3x1), base_lin_vel (3x1), j1_vel, j2_vel, j3_vel]
```

The full system state X and its time-derivative x_dot are shown below.

```
    X (19x1) = [q     (10x1),  v    ( 9x1)]
X_dot (19x1) = [q_dot (10x1),  v_dot (9x1)]
```

Note: X ≠ [q, q_dot], instead X = [q, v].
Similarly, X_dot ≠ [q_dot, q_ddot], instead X = [q_dot, v_dot].